How to deploy Open Layer app in a Node Js App?
I have built an openlayer app and after I run npm run build, I got created dist folder and placet in my nodejs appwhere I have my auth for accessing this map. I placed dist folder on the public folder. Dist folder has index.html and assets folder that has all the files minified.
but my problem is that when I run node app.js and enter my credentials, map is loaded but as html, not running. And the error in the console is :
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3001/public/dist/assets/index-Br06DeGN.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
but those errors are ok. I checked and the paths are ok.
What I have done wrong here ? Can someone help ?
